# Can the same object lock be checked at the same time by concurrent threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

How come if I have a statement like this:

```
private int sharedValue = 0;

public void SomeMethodOne()
{
   lock(this){sharedValue++;}
}

public void SomeMethodTwo()
{
   lock(this){sharedValue--;}
}
```

So for a thread to get into a lock it must first check if another thread is operating on it. If it isn't, it can enter and has to write something to memory, this surely cannot be atomic as it needs to read and write.

So how come it's impossible for one thread to be reading the lock, while the other is writing its ownership to it?

To simplify Why cannot two threads both get into a lock at the same time?

Comment: See another similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758088/how-are-atomic-operations-implemented-at-a-hardware-level

Comment: They are atomic.. specifically, they are an atomic update of the sync block index.. which is just an integer.

Comment: This is the point of locking - so that you can write code that is safe to be used by concurrent threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are basically asking how the lock works. How can the lock maintain internal state in an atomic manner without already having the lock built? It seems like a [chicken and egg problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) at first does it not?

The magic all happens because of a [compare-and-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) (CAS) operation. The CAS operation is a hardware level instruction that does 2 important things.

- It generates a memory barrier so that instruction reordering is constrained.
- It compares the contents of a memory address with another value and if they are equal then the original value is replaced with a new value. It does all of this in an atomic manner.

At the most fundamental level this is how the trick is accomplished. It is not that all other threads are blocked from reading while another is writing. That is totally the wrong way to think about it. What actually happens is that all threads are acting as writers simultaneously. The strategy is more optimistic than it is pessimistic. Every thread is trying to acquire the lock by performing this special kind of write called a CAS. You actually have access to a CAS operation in .NET via the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` (ICX) method. Every synchronization primitive can be built from this single operation.

If I were going to write a `Monitor`-like class (that is what the `lock` keyword uses behind the scenes) from scratch entirely in C# I could do it using the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` method. Here is an overly simplified implementation. Please keep in mind that this is most certainly *not* how the .NET Framework does it.<sup>1</sup> The reason I present the code below is to show you how it *could* be done in pure C# code without the need for CLR magic behind the scenes and because it might get you thinking about how Microsoft could have implemented it.

```
public class SimpleMonitor
{
    private int m_LockState = 0;

    public void Enter()
    {
        int iterations = 0;
        while (!TryEnter())
        {
            if (iterations < 10) Thread.SpinWait(4 << iterations);
            else if (iterations % 20 == 0) Thread.Sleep(1);
            else if (iterations % 5 == 0) Thread.Sleep(0);
            else Thread.Yield();
            iterations++;
        }
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        if (!TryExit())
        {
            throw new SynchronizationLockException();
        }
    }

    public bool TryEnter()
    {
        return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_LockState, 1, 0) == 0;
    }

    public bool TryExit()
    {
        return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_LockState, 0, 1) == 1;
    }
}
```

This implementation demonstrates a couple of important things.

- It shows how the ICX operation is used to atomically read and write the lock state.
- It shows how the waiting might occur.

Notice how I used `Thread.SpinWait`, `Thread.Sleep(0)`, `Thread.Sleep(1)` and `Thread.Yield` while the lock is waiting to be acquired. The waiting strategy is overly simplified, but it does approximate a [real life algorithm implemented in the BCL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10305721/158779) already. I intentionally kept the code simple in the `Enter` method above to make it easier to spot the crucial bits. This is not how I would have normally implemented this, but I am hoping it does drive home the salient points.

Also note that my `SimpleMonitor` above has a lot of problems. Here are but only a few.

- It does not handle nested locking.
- It does not provide `Wait` or `Pulse` methods like the real `Monitor` class. They are *really* hard to do right.

---

<sup>1</sup>*The CLR will actually use a special block of memory that exists on each reference type. This block of memory is referred to as the "sync block". The `Monitor` will manipulate bits in this block of memory to acquire and release the lock. This action may require a kernel event object. You can read more about it on [Joe Duffy's blog](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&ved=0CHkQFjAJ&url=http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/06/24/clr-monitors-and-sync-blocks/&ei=bcptUv2_CaTx2QX90YD4Aw&usg=AFQjCNEw8FUce5b5A-AmBktrq5yKak5AKA&sig2=HwJYz2VeH5yzr-8dAijV4Q&bvm=bv.55123115,d.b2I).*

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I was reading through the book by Duffy(Concurrent Programming on Windows) and it discussed Dekker's and Dijkstra's Algorithems through to what you mention above.

Comment: @user1743962: It is a good book. Be sure to read the section on spin waiting starting on pg. 767. That was another reference I used when contriving the waiting strategy in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`lock` in C# is used to create a `Monitor` object that is actually used for locking.

You can read more about `Monitor` in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx. The `Enter` method of the `Monitor` ensures that only one thread can enter the critical section at the time:

> Acquires a lock for an object. This action also marks the beginning of a critical section. No other thread can enter the critical section unless it is executing the instructions in the critical section using a different locked object.

BTW, you should avoid locking on `this` (`lock(this)`). You should use a private variable on a class (static or non-static) to protect the critical section. You can read more in the same link provided above but the reason is:

> When selecting an object on which to synchronize, you should lock only on private or internal objects. Locking on external objects might result in deadlocks, because unrelated code could choose the same objects to lock on for different purposes.